# perl split interesting behavior

Tags: perl, split

can somebody explain this weird behavior:

I hava path in a string and I want to split it for each backslash

```
my $path = "D:\Folder\AnotherFolder\file.txt";

my @folders = split('\', $path);
```

in the case above it won't work not even if escaping the backslash like this:

```
my @folders = split('\\', $path);
```

but in the case of a regexp it will work:

```
my @folders = split( /\\/, $path);
```

why is so?

Comment: Your escapes in the path are wrong. In a double quoted string, `\Folder` is interpreted as an escape sequence `\F`.

Comment: It is bad practice to use quotes around the separator pattern for `split` as it doesn't express the semantics properly and causes double compilation. Always use slashes, unless you want to pass a single-space string to invike the default behaviour, when `' '` is the correct choice.

Comment: @TLP yes I know, I usually put only single quotes for path. thanks

Comment: @Borodin very true, I usually do that, this was more of a curiosity I couldn't understand

Answer (score 6):

I think `amon` gave the best literal answer to your question in his comment:

> more explicitly: strings and regexes have different rules for escaping. If a string is used in place of a regex, the string literals suffer from double escaping

Meaning that `split '\\'` uses a string and `split /\\/` uses a regex.

As a practical answer, I wanted to add this:

Perhaps you should consider using a module suited for splitting paths. [`File::Spec`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aSpec) is a core module in Perl 5. And also, you have to escape backslash in a double quoted string, which you have not done. You can also use single quotes, which looks a bit better in my opinion.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Spec;

my $path = 'D:\Folder\AnotherFolder\file.txt';  # note the single quotes
my @elements = File::Spec->splitdir($path);
print Dumper \@elements;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'D:',
          'Folder',
          'AnotherFolder',
          'file.txt'
        ];
```

Comment: @AndreiDoanca It is the right tool for splitting paths, and it is portable and dependable. I am not sure what you are trying to do by splitting the path, but it looks like an XY-problem.

Comment: actually it isn't an XY-problem just a curiosity of mine :)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation by running:

```
perldoc -f split
```

you will see three forms of arguments that `split` can take:

```
split /PATTERN/,EXPR,LIMIT
split /PATTERN/,EXPR
split /PATTERN/
```

This means that even when you pass `split` a string as the first argument, `perl` is coercing it into a regex.

If we look at the warnings we get when trying to do something like this in [`re.pl`](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Devel-REPL-1.003025/lib/Devel/REPL.pm):

```
$ my $string_with_backslashes = "Hello\\there\\friend";
Hello\there\friend
$ my @arry = split('\\', $string_with_backslashes);
Compile error: Trailing \ in regex m/\/ at (eval 287) line 6.
```

we see that first, `'\\'` is interpolated as a backslash escape followed by an actual backslash, which evaluates to a single backslash.

`split` then puts the backslash we gave it, and coerces it to a regex as if we had written:

```
$ my @arry = split(/\/, $string_with_backslashes);
```

which doesn't work because there is only a single backslash which is interpreted as simply escaping the forward slash after it (without having a terminating `/`) to show that the regex has ended.

Comment: Actually, if it was escaping the slash, you would get the error `Search pattern not terminated`, meaning the operator was broken. This is something else.

Comment: more explicitly: strings and regexes have different rules for escaping. If a string is used in place of a regex, the string literals suffer from double escaping.

Comment: @user1436026 I did read the perldoc, but couldn't quite understand the innerworks, didn't know that whatever you put in '' still gets turned into and regexp

Answer (score 2):

One of the neater ways to extract the elements of a path is to extract all sequences of characters *other than* a path separator.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $path = 'D:\Folder\AnotherFolder\file.txt';
my @path = $path =~ m([^/\\]+)g;

print "$_\n" for @path;
```

**output**

```
D:
Folder
AnotherFolder
file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

When `split` is used in the form of `split STRING` and not `split REGEX`, the string is being converted into a regex. In your case `split '\\'` will be converted to `split /\/` since the first backslash is considered an escape character.

The correct way to do it is `split '\\\\'` which will be translated to `split /\\/`.

Comment: thanks very much for the explanation, really good info :) I understand now and see that it works  :)